# calling method in java which contains while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public List<String> CsvReaderGeneral(String CSVPATH,String AddStatement) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSVPATH));
    String input;
    int count = 0;
    while((input = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)    {
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println("Count : "+count);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSVPATH));
    br.readLine();
    String line=null;
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
     // String line="";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] cols = line.split(",");
        l.add(AddStatement);
    }
    System.out.println(l);
    return l;
}
```

I am calling above method here:

```
public List<String> CsvReaderIDStationSystemHealth() throws Exception{

        //return CsvReaderGeneral(STATIONSCSVPATH, STATIONSCOLOUMNVALUE);
        return CsvReaderGeneral(STATIONSCSVPATH, "cols[0]");
    }
```

My output is shown below:

Count : 101
[cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0], cols[0]........

It is printing `cols[0]` instead of the value in that location.

How to get values? Is there any other way to call this method?

Answer (score 1):

AddStatement = "cols[0]" and you're just printing it out in a loop without using the variable in any way.  I'm going to assume you're trying to add the first element of the line to the 'l' variable.   So your while loop should look like this.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] cols = line.split(",");
        l.add(cols[0]);
    }
```

You can't (easily) call a dynamically created variable with an input string.   If you're calling the method in hopes of having adjustable cols your method header should be

```
public List<String> CsvReaderGeneral(String CSVPATH,int colNum)
```

and your loop would be

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] cols = line.split(",");
        l.add(cols[colNum]);
    }
```

Comment: sometimes I have to use 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] cols = line.split(",");
        l.add("**** "+cols[4);
    } ]

That,s Why I want add to customized